# App crashing due to webview package in react native

Tags: android, react-native, highcharts, react-highcharts

```
<WebView
    style={styles.full}
    source={{html: concatHTML, baseUrl: 'web/'}}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    scalesPageToFit={true}
    scrollEnabled={false}
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
    androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled={true}
    removeClippedSubviews={true}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    startInLoadingState={true}
    renderLoading={displaySpinner}
    renderError={renderError}
/>
```

> I/ActivityManager: Process
> com.google.android.webview:sandboxed_process0:org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0:2
> (pid 563) has died: prcp BTOP

The above message logged just before the app got crashed. Actually, in the application we have used `"react-native-webview-bypass-ssl-errors": "11.26.1"` to bypass SSL errors and also to render `react-native-highcharts`.
How to solve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The react-native package is deprecated, so that means, that we dropped support for that package, and it now is in the hands of the community. I'm not sure if the issue is related to the wrapper itself, but If you need any support with this package, you can create an Issue in GitHub and might find some help there: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native